# How to display multiple callouts on an map objective -c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im new to iOS development(objective-c) and I have been asked to display multiple callouts after the map loads. I really don't know where to start so i would really appreciate form of help.

thanks in advance

Comment: Follow this tutorial it will give you brief idea. https://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial

Comment: Thanks Wolverine,helped a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [Map-kit Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial)

Here you can learn how to add a MapKit map to your app, zoom to a particular location , And show multiple locations on map-view.